# Setting up a "gaming" laptop

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I'll try to be as clear as possible.

System and tools:

- HP Pavilion Dv7 laptop (no Bluetooth, not sure if it has a nvidia card)
- Ubuntu 18.04 with updates
- Afterglow PS3 controller (with original USB dongle)

Software:

- Play On Linux with updates and current WINE
- Retroarch with updates

Problem:

- Play On Linux works with keyboard controls but can't get it to work with PS3 controller

What I've tried:

- Tried installing sixaxiscontrol.exe and moving the files where I needed them (wouldn't install)
- tried this: https://boilingsteam.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-make-controllers-work-in-wine/ (stopped all programs from recognizing my dongle controller and inputs, messed up various setups I had and forced me to reinstall, repair was not allowed, good thing I had backups)
- Checked permissions on software and in game (nothing)
- Screaming at it (obviously did nothing)

Please help.

Comment: Still seeking help. Please...

Comment: I think there's too many moving parts here for anyone to help you. Just the controller problems would take a fair amount of effort to solve, and any answers you get will never address all of the problems. Maybe break your issues down into chunks and solve those one at a time.

Comment: I know this makes me an apostate, but if you are serious about high-level gaming you probably want to run one of those _other_ platforms. Well, maybe just one specific _other_ platform. Though, since you are already running Wine, VirtualBox running Windows would probably also be an option.

Comment: Corrected the question to one solid topic, getting the controller to work in playonlinux. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Still no takers?